# ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android, zipexception

I can not build apk file. this is my error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener.class
```

I went through almost all similar problems here on stackoverflow and tried the solutions. Can anyone tell me what needs to be done to remove this issue.

Below are the dependencies that I am using in my project

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.eyalbira.loadingdots:loading-dots:1.0.2'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
compile 'com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.3.4'
compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.19@aar'
compile 'com.alexzh:circleimageview:1.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

and these are my libs:

[image]

Comment: What is your android studio version? Is it 3.0.1?

Comment: My android studio version is 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your dependencies have a duplicated **nineoldandroids** library.

You need to exclude it from your dependencies. One of the library containing nineoldandroids is **circleimageview**. You can exclude the library with:

```
compile ('com.alexzh:circleimageview:1.2.0') {
   exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
}
```

You need to find the other library which contains the nineoldandroid library.

A lazy solution is using configurations block in your module build.gradle (I really don't encourage to use the configurations):

```
configurations {
    // to avoid double inclusion of support libraries
    all*.exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
}

dependencies {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The other library that contains  the nineoldandroid is: com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1;                                                                     Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
compile ('com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1') {
           exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'}
```